# Recognizing lunar month by only looking the sky

Tags: lunar-calendar

Suppose somebody went on an island and don't have sense about time, dates, months. The only thing he has is seeing the sky. Is it possible to recognise which lunar month it is by just looking the sky? I ask this because I know how to see beginning of the lunar month, but how to recognise which month is it? So we can look at the Sun, Moon, the stars. Is there a way to figure that out?

Comment: The only thing you see in the sky is the sun, moon and stars. Unless he is an expert in astronomy, I don't think he can.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. As is your question mighgt be a better fit on [AstronomySE](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/) and hardly on-topic here. @Crimson why, all Bedouin were able to locate it, it's a matter of observation and training.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this might be a better fit on [AstronomySE](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I agree with Sassir.